# Where does MySQL's "show slave status" information come from?

Tags: mysql, replication

two files "master.info" and "relay-log.info" were deleted after I "reset slave"

I want to know why slave information still exists ~ confused >_<

I think it shouldn't display any message about slave ~ thanks ^_^

```
mysql> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: 
                  Master_Host: centos7
                  Master_User: repl
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: 
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 4
               Relay_Log_File: Centos6-relay-bin.000001
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Master_Log_File: 
             Slave_IO_Running: No
            Slave_SQL_Running: No
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 0
              Relay_Log_Space: 126
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 0
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That slave info is in RAM.

If you are running MySQL 5.6, run `RESET SLAVE ALL;`

If you are running MySQL 5.5, restart MySQL

If you are running MySQL 5.0/5.1, run the following:

```
STOP SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO master_host='';
```

These are the ways to make the `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` disappear from view

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: perfect ~~~!!!!!!!!!